# Visual Studio adds an empty file when adding a new class from within my .Net Core class designer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class, class-design, class-designer

I have the VS Class designer installed in my VS version and I am trying to create a class from within the class designer using Add -> Class. Then I give it a name and select "create a new file". Afterwards, it throws an error because it created an empty file with nothing in it. (Error: The code for _ is not ready to be read yet. In some cases, saving all files and generating again will fix issues.)

I don't know why this happens since I already worked with the class designer for a long time and this problem is completely new to me.

Also, normally when I right click on the name of the project there is usually the option "View" from which I can create a new class design corresponding to the current project. This option is also missing.

Any help is very welcome.

Comment: Please tell us the VS version?

Comment: I am using the current version 15.9.11 VS 2017